# Surjective function that has two of each element

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm trying to find a surjective function that is $[0,1]\to[0,1]$ that each value is exactly twice. I think that I found one: $$f(x)=\begin{cases}
x & x\in[0,\frac{1}{2})\\
1-x & x\in(\frac{1}{2},1]
\end{cases}$$

But I'm not sure how to show that all of her values can be calculated twice.

Comment: As is, this doesn't do what you want. You can modify it by changing $x$ to $2x$ and I think it will hit them all twice except for $1$.

Comment: Your function as you wrote it is not defined at $\frac{1}{2}$ and further is not even surjective.  There is no value of $x$ such that $f(x)=0.75$ for example.  You might do well to break this into two parts: Take a bijection from $[0,\frac{1}{2})$ to $[0,1]$ and couple that with a bijection from $[\frac{1}{2},1]$ to $[0,1]$.

Comment: If you are looking for a *continuous* such function, it cannot be done.  A proof of that will use the intermediate value theorem.

Comment: Sketch of a proof that no such continuous function can be surjective and hit every output exactly twice: Consider the four $x$ values such that they output either zero or one.  Call them $a<b<c<d$.  Case 1: $f(a)=f(b)=0$.  As the function is continuous, $a<\frac{a+b}{2}<b$, and $f(\frac{a+b}{2})>0$ there must be some point where $f$ takes the value of $\frac{1}{2}f(\frac{a+b}{2})$ at least once on each of the intervals $(a,\frac{a+b}{2}),(\frac{a+b}{2},b)$ and $(b,c)$ by the intermediate value theorem, i.e. at least three times, contradicting each value twice.  The other cases are analogous.

Answer (score 2):

No, that's not a solution.

1. Your function is not defined for $x=\frac12$.
2. Its range is $[0,\frac12)$, not $[0,1]$.

But you do have the property that every element in the range is hit twice.

**Hint** for making it work: Try to combine a *bijection* $[0,\frac12]\to [0,1]$ with a bijection $(\frac12,1]\to[0,1]$. For the latter you need a trick. Have you seen the "Hilbert's Hotel" construction for a bijection $[0,1]$ and $(0,1]$?

Answer (score 0):

For $x\in[\frac12,1]$ define $f(x)=2x-1$

For $x\in[0,\frac12)$ first consider a bijective function $g:[0,\frac12)\cap\Bbb Q\to(0,\frac12)\cap\Bbb Q$. It exists because both sets are infinite and countable. Then define
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}g(x)\text{ if }x\in\Bbb Q\\2x\text{ otherwise}\end{cases}$$

Comment: Your function $g(x)$ does not have $0$ in its range; how could the function take that value twice? (I understand it hits $0$ when $x=\frac12$, but I don’t think it does for $0\leq x<\frac12$.)

Answer (score 0):

Notice that $|[0,1]| = |[0,1] \times \{0,1\}|$. This follows from the Cantor–Schröder–Bernstein theorem: the $x\mapsto (x,0)$ is an injection from $[0,1] $ to $[0,1] \times \{0,1\}$, and for the converse direction consider the injection given by $(x,0) \mapsto \frac{x}3$ and $(x,1) \mapsto 1 - \frac{x}3$ for $x \in [0,1]$.

Now let $$\phi = (\phi_1, \phi_2): [0,1] \to [0,1] \times \{0, 1\}$$ be any bijection.

Notice that $\phi_1 : [0,1] \to [0,1]$ is a function which attains every value in $[0,1]$ exactly twice.

Namely, for every $y \in [0,1]$ there exists $x_1 \in [0,1]$ such that $\phi(x_1) = (y, 0)$ and there exists $x_2 \in [0,1]$ such that $\phi(x_2) = (y, 1)$. So $\phi_1(x_1) = \phi_1(x_2) = y$. Furthermore, $x_1$ and $x_2$ are the only such values because $\phi$ is bijective.